# Is an intersection between an interval and a set correct notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was solving a problem where I was supposed to write, $$x_i \in \{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}, i \in\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$$ Would it be correct notation if I wrote, $$x_i \in [4, 10] \cap \mathbb N, i \in[1, 6] \cap \mathbb N$$ Or is the second way of writing too cumbersome?

Comment: The correct symbols are $\in$ (`\in`) and $\cap$ (`\cap`) instead of $\epsilon$ and $\bigcap$.  Otherwise, the notation is correct.

Comment: @L.F. Thank you very much! I have edited the original question to fix the wrong symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both notations are correct. However, the first set explicitly writes out the elements while the second notation requires some extra 'work' to see which elements it consists of. So even though the second notation is more concice, the first notation is a bit more clear in my opinion.